# sass-loader Can't resolve @import url

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt.js with fastify.js ( fastify-vue-plugin ) and I am setting up my styling.

The scss compiles and works, but throws an error on build when I am trying to import a font from googlefonts as so:

```
// _variables.scss
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
```

```
// styles.scss
@import 'variables'; // i've tested this import, it works flawlessly.
```

The error I'm getting with `npm run dev` is this:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                           friendly-errors 04:00:16


 ERROR  in ./assets/scss/styles.scss                                                                              friendly-errors 04:00:16

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):                                            friendly-errors 04:00:16
Error: Can't resolve 'https:/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text&display=swap' in '/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/assets/scss'
    at onError (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:61:15)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at runAfter (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
    at innerCallback (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    at innerCallback (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:166:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at next (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
    at /Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ModuleKindPlugin.js:23:4
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/Users/home/Projects/voxicard-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 04:00:16
 @ ./assets/scss/styles.scss 4:14-301 14:3-18:5 15:22-309
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi eventsource-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&name=client&path=/__webpack_hmr/client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

```
// nuxt.config.js
...
css: [
    './assets/scss/styles.scss'
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources'
  ],
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false,
    bootstrapVueCSS: false
  },
  styleResources:{
    scss:[
        './assets/scss/*.scss',
    ]
  },
...
```

I have another project where I've used sass-loader with the same font import and that worked, though it wasn't a Nuxtjs project.

What is not working here?

Comment: styleResources is for variables and you including there all your scss. Thats not right

Comment: @Aldarund I changed that to my `_variables.scss` and the error still persists.

Comment: @Aldarund ok, i just removed that line from under `styleResources` and it works now, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Aldarund's comment, I managed to fix this error by removing this line from my `nuxt.config.js`

```
// nuxt.config.js
styleResources : {
    scss: [
        './assets/scss/*.scss' // <<<< I Removed this line and kept this array empty.
    ]
}
```